# Is crawl budget and link juice being wasted to URLs with hashes?

Tags: seo, url, googlebot, hash, link-juice

On my site I have internal links to URLs with hashes in them, like this one:

```
https://example.com/page.html#music
```

`https://example.com/page.html#music` has canonical tag with URL pointing to `https://example.com/page.html`. Hashes do not change content of the page in any way.

Google (and other search engines) cut out hashes in URLs and index pages without hashes.

**But is Google's crawl budget and/or link juice (internal PageRank) wasted to such URLs with hashes or not?**

Comment: This isn't something you should have to consider IMO. If Google's crawl budget was sufficiently "wasted" crawling these type of URLs, to be detrimental to your site then it would suggest a problem with Google's crawler IMO. The fact that you've set canonical tags should eliminate "link juice" being _wasted_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs with hashes are generally ignored by majority of Search Engines as it contains a block of information which can be found in the same page. This is not related to the crawl budget or link juice, as the URL is treated as one single landing page. In majority of cases, links with "#" are given less importance.

The best way to pass value to whatever attribute you want to showcase using "#" is to use headers (H2, H3, H4, H5, H6). If you're looking to rank your webpage to show results in Google as QA or Extensions, schema or snippets would be the right choice.

> Notes/Q?

I've never run an experiment to get a page with URL containing "#" indexed and is generally set to be omitted in Google Search Console.

Assuming your page is too lengthy and the "#" URL is forced to be indexed, what kind of result are you looking for?

Comment: Developers use hashes in URLs collect some click data on links. So I wanted to see if this doesn't interfere with crawling/indexing process.

Comment: This doesn't interfere with any crawling/indexing process as far as I know.